# JavaScript html Button Disable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button

```
<button onClick="increase = setInterval(increasing, 400);
    clearInterval(decrease);"><b>increase (+)</b>
</button>

<button onClick="clearInterval(increase);
    clearInterval(decrease);"><b>Stop</b
</button>

<button onClick="decrease = setInterval(decreasing, 400);
    clearInterval(increase)"><b>decrease  (-)</b>
</button>
```

When I press increase_button, can this button disable?  When I press stop_button, can increase_button enable?

How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: In HTML, attributes should not stretch across lines.  Also, for unobtrusive javascript, you should move your onClick handlers into a javascript file anyway. like this: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/y7n2s4gL/5/